# Can I combine boolean and null checks somehow? I would like to know if this kotlin method can be simplied further

Tags: kotlin, nullable, simplify, simplification

I am new to Kotlin and I would like to know the most optimized way in which I can simplify the following method.

If the amount is payable by person X then I need to return the amount payable, else I need to return 0.

In the code below ***payments*** is an object that is nullable. It contains ***retailAmount*** which is also an object that's nullable. ***retailAmount*** contains ***baseCharges*** which is a Double. (Also if ***payments*** or ***retailAmount*** is null I need to return 0)

```
// get charges payable by X(Retailer/Shopkeeper/Customer)
fun getChargesPayableByX(personX: String): Double {
    // are charges payable by X(Retailer/Shopkeeper/Customer)?
    if (areChargesPayableByX(personX)) {  
        return payments?.retailAmount?.baseCharges ?: 0.0
    }
    return 0.0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
fun getChargesPayableByX(personX: String): Double = 
    areChargesPayableByX(personX).takeIf{it == true}?.let{ payments?.retailAmount?.baseCharges } ?: 0.0
```

Comment: Would this maybe be simpler as `payments?.retailAmount?.baseCharges.takeIf { it != null && areChargesPayableByX(personX) } ?: 0.0` ?

Comment: @YoniGibbs Anything that works for you. These are just different ways of writing the same thing. It does not actually optimize your code.

Comment: @SaeedEntezari and Yoni Gibbs Thanks to your replies I just learned about the takeIf operator